# How to call a subroutine to multiple rows in a column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, subroutine

I'm working on a project to develop features to train a machine learning classifier with a set of text reviews. The feature I'm having trouble with is to count if a review has the specific keyword "amazing" in it, and then display a 1 or a 0 in a column next to the review depending if the keyword was found or not.

The main issue being that my values wont display in the column. This is the only coding/programming course I have taken and I am a beginner.

```
'this feature is used to find the keyword "amazing" in the reviews
Sub FindKeywordAmazing()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WordCount As Integer
    Dim Line As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
        WordCount = 0
        Line = 2
        Count = 0

        'using an If statement to update the word count if the keyword amazing is present
        For Each cell In Range("A2:A1001")
            If InStr(cell.Value, "amazing") > 0 Then
                WordCount = WordCount + 1
            Else
                WordCount = 0
            End If

            Count = WordCount
            Range("C" & Line).Value = Count
            Line = Line + 1
        Next

        'calling the sub with the value of the word count to the C column

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the intent to do this programmatically? Because this can be done with a simple formula.

Comment: yes i am supposed to program different features to distinguish two types of text, ya its an intro course they don't expect crazy features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, perhaps a simpler way to do this:

```
Range("C2:C1001").Formula = "=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""amazing"",A2))"
```

Change `SEARCH` to `FIND` if you want this to be case-sensitive.

[image]

For a search on two words, perhaps:

```
Range("C2:C1001").Formula = "=--OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""amazing"",""great""},A2)))"
```

Change the `OR` to `AND` if you want both to be found.

Comment: thank you for that, that helps me. Do you know how i could look for two keywords at once, or either one keyword or another? For example, looking for amazing and great within a review, or looking for amazing or great within the review. Im writing it as a subroutine