# Count the number of uppercase words in a text review

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, text

I want to count the number of uppercase words in a data set of movie reviews (A2:A1001) and paste the results to column E.

I am having trouble getting any response from the sub on the spreadsheet.

```
Sub UppercaseWordCount()
    Dim ArraySplit() As String
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim NextWord As String
    Dim Line As Integer
        Count = 0
        ArraySplit = Split("A2:A1001", " ")
        Line = 2
        
        'splitting each review into an array and using lower
        'and upper bounds with Ucase function to get a count
        'len function used to split up words from single characters
        
        For X = LBound(ArraySplit) To UBound(ArraySplit)
            NextWord = ArraySplit(X)
            If NextWord = UCase(NextWord) And Len(NextWord) >= 2 Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next
        
        'calling the sub to column E with a count for each review
        Range("E" & Line).Value = Count
        Line = Line + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: `Split("A2:A1001", " ")` - your syntax is off. But you would have to loop through each cell in the range and use split on that.

Comment: Are you [Nate House](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13118363/nate-house)? Really seems like a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508901/need-help-calling-a-subroutine-to-multiple-rows-in-a-column-in-vba) haha.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, I was a bit confused with how to setup the range, do you know how I would setup the loop to go through each cell A2:A1001? Thank you!

Comment: `For Each cell in Range("A2:A1001")`?

Comment: I was about to offer to post some code, but I think if you follow BigBen's link you will see how to do this with formulae.

Comment: @SJR - well this is uppercase counting.... it'd be a different formula. It's just that there are similarities to that question I answered.

Comment: The code is almost identical, down to the indentations. Anyway you can do this without VBA @OP.

Comment: Using VBA and BigBen's suggestion above you would then use Split on each `cell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You could convert to a custom function if doing repeatedly.

```
Sub UppercaseWordCount()

Dim ArraySplit() As String
Dim X As Long 'long better than integer
Dim Count As Long
Dim NextWord As String
Dim r As Range

'splitting each review into an array and using lower
'and upper bounds with Ucase function to get a count
'len function used to split up words from single characters
For Each r In Range("A2:A1001") 'loop through defined range
    ArraySplit = Split(r, " ")  'split each cell using space delimiter
    For X = LBound(ArraySplit) To UBound(ArraySplit) 'everything else as before
        NextWord = ArraySplit(X)
        If NextWord = UCase(NextWord) And Len(NextWord) >= 2 Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    'calling the sub to column E with a count for each review
    r.Offset(, 4).Value = Count 'can use offset rather than defining a new variable
    Count = 0 'reset count
Next r

End Sub
```